# Trying to get the 2nd th element in the table using Vue 3 template in Cypress

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, cypress

In my cypress test im trying to access the 2nd  element in a table  from the vue template:

```
<template>
  <table id="table" class="table" data-cy="table">
    <thead class="table-head" data-cy="table-head">
      <tr class="table-row" data-cy="table-row">
        <th id="table-updatable" v-show="massUpdatable" class="table-cell" data-cy="table-head-updatable">
          <input type="checkbox" data-cy="table-head-checkbox"/>
        </th>
        <th
          id="table-head-icons"
          data-cy="table-head-cell"
          class="table-cell"
          :class="orderClasses(column.order_by)"
          v-for="(column, columnKey) in props.columns"
          @click="orderTable(column.order_by)"
          :key="columnKey"
        >
          <div class="table-header" data-cy="table-header-div">
          {{ $t(column.name) }}
          <font-awesome-icon
            data-cy="table-icon-arrowUp"
            class="asc"
            :icon="['fas', 'arrow-up']"
            fixed-width
          ></font-awesome-icon>
          <font-awesome-icon
            data-cy="table-icon-arrowDown"
            class="desc"
            :icon="['fas', 'arrow-down']"
            fixed-width
          ></font-awesome-icon>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th
          data-cy="table-icon-actions"
          class="table-cell actions-cell"
          :class="'actions-amount-' + filteredActionsLength(false)"
          v-if="Object.keys(props.actions).length > 0"
        ></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body" data-cy="table-body" :class="fullPage ? 'table-body-full' : ''">
      <tr
        class="table-row"
        v-for="(row, rowKey) in rows"
        :key="rowKey"
        :class="row.deleted_at ? 'archived' : ''"
      >
        <td 
          data-cy="table-data-updatable"
          v-show="massUpdatable" class="table-cell">
          <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td
          data-cy="table-data-cell"
          class="table-cell" 
          v-for="(column, columnKey) in props.columns"
          :key="columnKey"
        >
          <table-boolean-column
            data-cy="table-boolean-column"
            v-if="column.type === 'boolean'"
            :value="row[columnKey]"
          ></table-boolean-column>
          <table-event-column
            data-cy="table-event-column"
            v-else-if="column.type === 'event'"
            :value="row[columnKey]"
          >
          </table-event-column>
          <template v-if="column.type === 'date'">
            {{
              row[columnKey] !== undefined
                ? row[columnKey].toLocaleDateString() +
                  " " +
                  row[columnKey].toLocaleTimeString()
                : ""
            }}
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            {{ parseValue(row[columnKey]) }}
          </template>
        </td>
        <td
          class="table-cell actions-cell"
          :class="'actions-amount-' + filteredActionsLength(row)"
          v-if="Object.keys(props.actions).length > 0"
        >
          <template v-for="(action, actionKey) in filteredActions(row)">
            <table-button
              data-cy="table-button"
              v-if="showButtons(row) || action.action === 'showMetadata'"
              @click="executeAction(action.action, row.id)"
              :key="actionKey"
              :icon="action.icon"
              :type="action.type"
              v-on:load-data="loadData"
              :content="$t(action.tooltip)"
            >
            </table-button>
          </template>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-cy="table-row-isLoading" v-if="isLoading" class="table-row">
        <div class="loader" data-cy="loader-loading">
          {{ $t("message.loading") }}
          <font-awesome-icon
            :icon="['fad', 'spinner-third']"
            class="loading-icon"
            fixed-width
          />
        </div>
      </tr>
      <tr v-if="lastPageLoaded" data-cy="table-row-lastPage" class="table-row">
        <div class="loader" data-cy="loader-endPage">
          {{ $t("message.final") }}
          <font-awesome-icon
            :icon="['fad', 'check']"
            class="success-icon"
            fixed-width
          />
        </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

im triyng to check if the font awesome icon is indeed really showing up
i did the following to no avail:

```
   it('has fa arrow icons', () => {
        cy.mount(TableList2, {
          props: { actions: true, massUpdatable: undefined, columns: true, rows: true, isLoading: false, lastPageLoaded: true, fullPage: true }
        }) 
  cy.get('[data-cy="table-head"] th[data-cy="table-head-cell"]')
      .eq(1) // Select the second <th> element (index is zero-based)
      .find('font-awesome-icon') // Find Font Awesome icons within the second <th>
      .should('have.length.gt', 0); // Assert that at least one Font Awesome icon exists
```

what am i missing here, it expects to find it but never does..
im also trying to see if on ascending it appears or not and also on descending, the font is not visible by default , only on click.

Answer (score 3):

Your selector is too specific:

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="table-head"] th[data-cy="table-head-cell"]')
```

The above query yields only one `<th>` since there is only one with `data-cy="table-head-cell"`.

So `.eq(1)` fails are you are trying to find the 2nd out of a list of one.

Either of these will work instead

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="table-head"] th[data-cy="table-head-cell"]')
  .find('font-awesome-icon');
  // .should('have.length.gt', 0)   // redundant assertion
```

or

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="table-head"] th')
  .eq(1)
  .find('font-awesome-icon');
```